# "invalid use of void expression": copy data from addr 1 to addr 2

Tags: c, void, memcpy, void-pointers

I tried to write my function like "memcpy" in C to copy a block of data from a source address to a destination address.

In line `*dst_addr++ = *src_addr++;`, the error is appeared: "invalid use of void expression"

The function I wrote:

```c
void MemCpy(void *src_addr, void *dst_addr, int length)                
{
    while(length--)
    {
        // copy by single byte
        *dst_addr++ = *src_addr++;
    }

    return dst_addr;
}
```

I used `void` to point to any object type if i need it later.

Why did I use the "void" wrong? Could someone explain my mistake?

Comment: Type `void` has no size. You must cast to some other pointer type like `char*` if you want to access the memory. GCC includes an extension that allowes pointer arithmetics with `void*` but dereferencing will not work with GCC either.

Comment: NB: Why `return dst_addr` for a `void` function?

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems in your code:

- void has no size and you cannot dereference void pointers nor perform pointer arithmetic on them
- you forgot the `*` in `void *MemCpy(...`

Correct code:

```
void *MemCpy(void *src_addr, const void *dst_addr, size_t length)
{
  const char *s = src_addr;
  char *d = dst_addr;

  while (length--)
    *d++ = *s++;

  return dst_addr;
}
```

BTW in the original `memcpy`, the first parameter is the destination pointer, so your `MemCpy` function is not quite the same as the original `memcpy`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot perform pointer arithmetics over `void*`. You have to cast to appropriate type.